# For each problems Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I'd like to ask if my query is correct.

```
 @foreach ($indemnity_benefits->where(['indemnity_benefit_type' => 'Ee', 'indemnity_benefit_group' => 'Basic Benefits'])->get() as $key => $benefit)
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="bBenefitEeDesc[]" value="{{$benefit->indemnity_benefit_desc}}">
                        <span class="p-2">{{$benefit->indemnity_benefit_desc}}</span>
                    </td>
                    <td><input style="width: 75px;" name="bBenefitEeMaxDays[]" value="{{old('bBenefitEeMaxDays.'.$key, $benefit->indemnity_benefit_maxdays)}}" class="form-control form-control-sm"></td>
                    {{-- @for ($index = 0; $index < $noOfCols; $index++)
                        <td><input name="bBenefitEeValue{{$key}}[]" value="{{old('bBenefitEeValue'.$key.'.'.$index, '')}}" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm"></td>
                    @endfor --}}

                    @foreach ($indemnity_values->where('indemnity_benefit_id', $benefit->id)->get() as $item)
                        <td><input name="" value="{{$item->indemnity_benefit_value}}" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm"></td>
                    @endforeach

                </tr>
                @endforeach
```

When I put $benefit->id in the second for each only one row with columns appear. Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdT8P.png).

Here are the queries:

```
 $sob_indemnity = SobGhIndemnityComprehensive::where('rfq_version_id', $rfq_version_id)->where('type', 'Indemnity')->first();

    //Indemnity Levels
    $sob_indemnity_levels = SobghIndemnityLevel::where('sob_gh_ind_comp_id', $sob_indemnity->id);
    $indemnity_benefits = SobghIndemnityBenefit::where('sob_gh_ind_comp_id', $sob_indemnity->id);
    $indemnity_values = SobghIndemnityBenefitsValue::where('sob_gh_ind_comp_id', $sob_indemnity->id);
```

Comment: Please post from which part of the code `$indemnity_values` is coming from.

Comment: I don't understand when you mention `When I dont put $benefit->id`

Comment: It was supposed to be, "When i put" sorry my bad

Comment: Well if you are getting just one object when you add the `$benefit->id`, the problem might be in the `$indemnity_values`. I don't see any problems coming from the code samples that you gave to us. I recommend you to debug `$indemnity_values` and see if this variable is holding the values that you are expecting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$indemnity_values` is a mutable object, so on your first line you are calling:

```
$indemnity_values
    ->where('indemnity_benefit_id', 1)
    ->get()
```

And on your second line you are calling the following that is obviously returning an empty collection.

```
$indemnity_values
    ->where('indemnity_benefit_id', 1)
    ->where('indemnity_benefit_id', 2)
    ->get()
```

you need to `clone` your query:

```
@foreach ((clone $indemnity_values)->where('indemnity_benefit_id', $benefit->id)->get() as $item)
```

Comment: did it this way `(clone $indemnity_values)->where('indemnity_benefit_id', $benefit->id)->get() as $item`